# Weird bug from from inner class

Tags: java, android

I got this weird error.And I can't figured out why this is happening.

Here is the problem

If I put this code inside of `firebaseproblem.onDataChange` I got an error.

```
String pl = "Ali";
     items[0] = pl;
```

If I put anywhere else it works perfectly... It is `items[0]` for debugging purposes

Error Log

```
07-20 12:16:06.605 2720-2720/azcrew.eatapp E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                at azcrew.eatapp.halfdone.listComp$2.onDataChange(listComp.java:98)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
07-20 12:16:06.845 2720-2720/azcrew.eatapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: azcrew.eatapp, PID: 2720
                                                         java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                             at azcrew.eatapp.halfdone.listComp$2.onDataChange(listComp.java:98)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Here is the full code

```
public class listComp extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    String[] id;
    String[] items = new String[20];
    int index = -1;
    static String pl;
    listMVP l = new listMVP();

    private static final String TAG = "test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_comp);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listcomp);

        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        id = b.getStringArray("id");

        firebaseproblem1();

        removingnull();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int d, long l) {
                String a = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                for(int ind = 0; d<items.length;ind++){
                 if(items[ind].equals(a)){
                        index = ind;
                     break;
                    }
                }
                //intentIn();
            }
        });
}


    private void firebaseproblem1() {
        for(int i=0; i<id.length;i++){
            if(id[i]!= null){
                DatabaseReference ref5 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference q = ref5.child("Restoran").child(id[i]).child("id");

                l.setI(i);
                final int finalI = i;
                q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    pl = "Ali";
                    items[0] = pl;
                }

                @Override
                 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void removingnull() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s: items){

            if(s!= null){
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        items = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }

    private void intentIn() {
        Bundle c = new Bundle();
        c.putString("resId",id[index]);
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, ListMain.class);
        i1.putExtras(c);
        startActivity(i1);
    }
}
```

Comment: initialise the `item = new String[20]` in `onCreate`

Comment: initialiseing item oncreate doesnt change a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onDataChanged` function may be called any time in the future.

In the meantime, your code has called the `removingnull` function, which has reset the `items` array to an empty array.

> If I put anywhere else it works perfectly

That is because that is executed synchronously before the `removingnull` function and thus the `items` array is still a `String[20]`

You can Log a few messages just to convince yourself of the order of execution of your code.

---

Suggested fix:

Forget the array, let items be a `List<String>`, you will not run into this kind of problems.

Comment: well i put it not onDataChanged but in firebaseproblem1 method it is working and listview shows the string. i tried to items[i] which in logic it will work. but then i got an error from android studio to copy i to final temp variable and i got the same error

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Added a suggestion to the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help.